# stylelint not working because of template literals

Tags: interpolation, styled-components, stylelint

```
const ModalMent = styled.span`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  ${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.body2};
  width: 14.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
  margin-top: 2.4rem;
`;
```

in this code, stylelint doesn't work.
the point is `${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.body2};` here.
if I comment out this line, it works well.

//After linting

```
const ModalMent = styled.span`
  margin-top: 2.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
  /* ${({ theme }) => theme.fonts.body2}; */
  width: 14.4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
`;
```

So I thought the return type of `theme.fonts.body2` is wrong, so stylelint seems to be unable to recognize it properly.

here is code where return font property

//theme.ts

```
const FONT = ({ family, weight, size, lineHeight }: Font): RuleSet => {
  return css`
    line-height: ${lineHeight}rem;
    font-family: ${family};
    font-size: ${size}rem;
    font-weight: ${weight};
  `;
};

const fonts = {
  head1: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 600, size: 2.8, lineHeight: 3.4 }),
  head2: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 700, size: 2.2, lineHeight: 3 }),

  title1: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 600, size: 1.8, lineHeight: 2.4 }),
  title2: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 400, size: 1.6, lineHeight: 2 }),

  body1: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 500, size: 1.6, lineHeight: 2.4 }),
  body2: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 500, size: 1.4, lineHeight: 2 }),
  body3: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 400, size: 1.4, lineHeight: 2 }),
  body4: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 500, size: 1.2, lineHeight: 1.6 }),

  button1: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 500, size: 1.6, lineHeight: 2 }),
  button2: FONT({ family: 'Pretendard Variable', weight: 400, size: 1.6, lineHeight: 2 }),
};
```

I'm not sure if my approach is correct. However, I don't know where and how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate your help.

also here is my .stylelintrc

```
{
  "processors": ["stylelint-processor-styled-components"],
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-recommended",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components",
    "stylelint-config-prettier",
    "stylelint-config-concentric-order"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "customSyntax": "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js"
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "color-named": "never"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js"` custom syntax, `stylelint-processor-styled-components` processor and `stylelint-config-prettier` shared config packages are deprecated.

You can use the more modern `postcss-styled-syntax` custom syntax, which supports that interpolation line. The Stylelint team also suggests using the standard config over the recommended one.

1. Ensuring your using the latest version of the packages:

```
npm i -D stylelint@latest stylelint-config-standard postcss-styled-syntax
```

2. Configure Stylelint:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard", "stylelint-config-recess-order"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.{ts,tsx}"],
      "customSyntax": "postcss-styled-syntax"
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "color-named": "never"
  }
}
```